# How do I perform arithmetic operations on values in a dropdown list in excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need a way of performing some caliber of arithmetic operations on values within a dropdown list in a cell. The output of the operation would be another dropdown list in a third cell. I am aware that I could just as easily make an array with the values "behind the scenes", but I need the values in both the initial and final lists to be visible in my spreadsheet.

An example of this would be as such (using pseudo code):

```
A1 = 5
B1 = (1,2,3,4)      <--dropdown list
C1 = A1 + B1  

C1 = (6,7,8,9)      <-- resulting dropdown list
```

Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a list for the dropdowns it is possible:

[image]

`A1` contains a number (`5`)

`B1` contains a dropdown from the list in range `F1:F5`

`C1` contains a dropdown from the list in range `H1:H5`

`F2:F5` contain 4 numbers (as shown)

`H2:H5` contain a formula (as shown)

One drawback of this method is that if you pick a number from the dropdown list, it won't update should you change the numbers in `A1` and/or `F2:F5`